# Irrationality of cubic threefold (before Clemens and Griffiths)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I came across [this notice](https://www.nature.com/articles/162563b0), which seems to say Fano proved that a general cubic threefold is irrational back in 1940s. I'm interested in seeing this work, especially a proof without intermediate Jacobian. However, I did not find the original paper or a good exposition. Does anyone know Fano's approach?

**Update**: Carlo found Fano's original paper, which is great! However, I can hardly follow the mathematics in it (translated by machine) and I'm not sure if it is the language barrier. Meanwhile, I found a [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.07390.pdf) that cited Fano's paper saying Fano's work is not considered rigorous. So the question remains: What is Fano's method, and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Indeed, I have added a link to a critical discussion of Fano's work.

Comment: You can also find a critical discussion of Fano's work in Roth' *Algebraic Threefolds* (Springer Ergebnisse, 1955), around p. 94-96. Beware that this is not written in EGA style...

Comment: Dear @abx, thank you for the reference. This is probably the reference I'm looking for, but I do find it difficult to follow the exposition though, especially with unfamiliar terminologies and notations. Do you know if Fano's method was carried out later by someone else?

Comment: Yes, by Iskovskih and Manin in the paper quoted by Carlo.

Comment: Dear @abx, I’m particularly interested in cubic threefold, does birational rigidity proves irrationality of cubic threefold as well?

Answer (score 6):

The reference is Gino Fano, *Nuove ricerche sulle varietà algebriche a tre dimensioni a curve-sezioni canoniche*, published by the Papal Academy in 1948 (summarized in 1945):

- [Acta Pont.
  Acad. Scient. 9 (1945), p. 163-167](http://www.bdim.eu/item?id=GM_Fano_1945_1)
- [Comment. Pont. Acad. Sci. 11 (1948), p. 635-720](http://www.bdim.eu/item?id=GM_Fano_1948_1)

It's in Italian (with an abstract in Latin); I guess Google translate can help.

---

Fano's proof is critically discussed by 
[Iskovskih and Manin](https://dx.doi.org/10.1070/SM1971v015n01ABEH001536) (1971):

> The idea of the proof consists of verifying the incompatibility of
> singularities of large multiplicity $\nu_i$ on surfaces of small
> degree $4n$ with the unfixedness (or only positively) of this system
> of surfaces. In this connection it is necessary to examine a series of
> cases separately, depending on the position of the singularity
> $B_{i-1}$, with maximum multiplicity $\nu_i$. In almost all of these
> cases Fano's arguments do not withstand critical examination.